# How to remove/renew 'artists' in a specific Axes in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, matplotlib

I've wrote a function to plot some lines and patterns on a specified Axe with `plt.plot` and `plt.fill`

Simplified code is like below:

```
class plotPatterns(object):
    def __init__(self, dataarr, ax=None): 
    # read-in parameters and check if is valid
        self.ax = self._check_ax(ax)
        self.fig = self.ax.figure
        self.data = dataarr
        # ...initialize of other parameters
        self._plotting(reload_init=0)

    def _check_ax(self, ax=None):
    # check if there is a specified Axe, create one if not
        if ax is None:
            fig = plt.figure()
            ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        return ax

    def _plotting(self, reload_init=0):
        # ...caculations with self.data
        #lines = self.ax.plot(x, y,)
        #fills = self.ax.fill(datafill_x, y,)
        #setxb = self.ax.set_xlim([min(self.trace_offset) - 2 * self.trace_scale, 
        #                          max(self.trace_offset) + 2 * self.trace_scale])
        #setyb = self.ax.set_ylim([self.t_end, self.t_start])
```

As you can see, an option ***reload_init=0*** is in function `_wiggle_plotting`.
The scenario I'm thinking of is:

If the user renewed a parameter in the class and manually called `_wiggle_plotting(reload_init=1)`, for example:

```
wp = plotPatterns(data1, ax)
wp.data = data1_filtered
wp.plotPatterns._plotting(1)
```

the following steps should be done:

1. Remove all changes been done in previous call of `_wiggle_plotting` and prevent altering the others
2. Redo the plotting part

Since I cannot use `plt.cla()` in this case, I'm thinking to allocate a new variable like:

```
    def __init__(self, dataarr, ax=None): 
        # ...paras initialize 
        self.plot_record = []
    def _wiggle_plotting(self, reload_init=0):
        if reload_init==1:
            # ...remove all artist stored in the last list of self.plot_record
            self.plot_record.remove(self.plot_record[-1])
        # ...caculations
        # ...plottings
        self.plot_record.append([lines, fills, setxb, setyb])
```

Hence, the problem I have is:

1. This seems a little bit stupid... is my logic doing right here?
   Or is there any advanced methods to perform?
2. I have no idea how to perform the removal of all artist efficiently. Is there a function I can remove the specified artists once and for all?
3. Lastly, please correct me if I'm using the term 'artist' wrong.

Comment: I do not understand why you cannot clear the axes. But if you are convinced that you want to remove the artists, you can `artist.remove()` and if necessary (e.g. due to memory issues) delete it afterwards, `del artist`.

Comment: The reason I can't `plt.cla()` is because something else might already in the Axes before the call of `plotWiggle()`. And I want to keep those. Anyway, thanks a lot for your advice. I've actually got some ideas from it, will try it out